# Create a DataFrame from a csv (url source) with scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv separated with comma stored online `(https : //xxx . com/xx/xx.csv)` .
I can get it like that :

`import scala.io.Source`

`val stringCsv = Source.fromURL(url,"UTF-8").mkString`

Now i want to convert `stringCsv` into a Spark DataFrame **without header**.

Answer (score 0):

I am guess that Source is scala.io.Source which would return an iterator. You could just get the LineIterator out of it, skip the first line and than turn it into a DataFrame.

This would work like this:

```
val raw = Source.fromURL(url,"UTF-8")

// skip the header
raw.next

// convert to DF
import spark.implicits._
val df = raw.toList.toDF

// here you end up with a dataframe of strings (So a row with a single column).
```

But that would be quite inefficient for bigger files. The spark way would be:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles
spark.sparkContext.addFile(spark.sparkContext.addFile(url)) 
val df = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("sep", ";")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("header", "true")
  .load("file://"+SparkFiles.get("yourfile.csv"))
```

There you have the option to define if your input has a header or not (besides a lot of other stuff). The trick might be that `spark.sparkContext.addFile(url)` register your file under the file name and not the full path (so URL like https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IBM/knative-serverless/master/src/destination/cities.csv would be registered under `cities.csv`)

Comment: It doesnt work because my csv is online.
`No FileSystem for scheme: https`

Comment: I update the examples to a) convert a plain string into a df and also the "spark" solution which should be prefered